# Fancy asking me that!

Tags: meaning, sarcasm

What does "fancy asking me that!" mean?
I reckon it's something like "how dare you ask me something like this" in a sarcastic way. Is it?

Comment: Please use the **[edit]** link to tell us what you did not understand about the definition provided by your dictionary for the English verb _to fancy._

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fancy

Comment: The expression does not have a fixed meaning. It can be used seriously, sarcastically, playfully, introspectively, inscrutably, aloofly, etc. -- all of which will change what it should *mean* to the listener.

Answer (score 5):

Peter has hit around the issue, but not really on the mark. In fact, *fancy* is a fancy (and somewhat archaic) synonym for *imagine*:

> **fancy** *v*
>   2. To imagine or suppose: *"I fancy she is an exceedingly proud woman" (Jane Austen).*

Your quote is an expression of wonderment mixed with indignation: "Imagine asking me that!"

Answer (score 0):

> **Fancy** asking me that!

is usually said in a surprised voice.  It could mean

> **Unbelieveable** asking me that!
>   **Incredible** asking me that!

and is more light hearted, but would not usually mean something as confrontational as

> How dare you, asking me that!

Whether it is sarcastic or not would depend on additional context.